# XL-Connector With Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, sfdc, sfdc-metadata-api

Using XL-Connector with Salesforce is there any way to allow the users only to export the data and restrict Insert/Update/Upsert/Delete operations using XL-Connector. even users having read write permissions on salesforce objects.

Restrict Insert/Update/Upsert/Delete operations using XL-Connector with Salesforce